# Does work need to be done to a quantum state to change it?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, energy, quantum-information, energy-conservation

Today in Quantum we talked about a 3 component quantum channel; maximally mixed light flowing into a linear filter oriented to 0 degrees, to through a phase retarder, then through another linear filter oriented at 90 degrees. If the phase retarder were removed, no light would make it through the channel, but with it, light becomes circularly polarized allowing some of it to flow through the second filter. I guess another assumption is that there are enough photons to approximate something like a planewave.

So here's my question(s):

Is the phase retarder doing work on the light to change its state? Or is energy from the light somehow being redirected to itself to change the state thereby attenuating the light? Or is it none of these, can the light have its state changed with no exchange in energy required?

The last one makes me feel like the second law of thermodynamics is being violated but I honestly don't know enough to say that confidently. It was my (maybe misguided) understanding that energy exchange was required for information to mutate. Maybe this answers my own question, but if I think about a single photon that happens to make it through the channel unschathed, I guess it doesn't make sense for a *portion of its quanta* to go into changing its state. Maybe I'm most confused about what it takes to change a state and if it's different classically vs in quantum.

Hope this wasn't too rambly. Thanks for any clarification!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by filter and phase retarder you mean polarizer and something like a half-wave plate respectively (please correct me if I am wrong). Algebraically, such optical elements for single polarizations are defined as [Jones matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_calculus) in Hamiltonian mechanics. They are by definition operators for non-attenuating media.

So, within the framework of closed quantum systems, nothing can be said about the actual thermodynamics of the phase retardation. The exact energetics of the phase retarding medium would require a good estimation of the actual potential experienced by a photon in the medium (e.g. using first principles calculations), like the $\overrightarrow{B}\cdot{\overrightarrow{S}}$ form in the Stern-Gerlach experiment, and perhaps some formalisms of light-matter interactions. The thermodynamics of the phenomena would then have to be extrapolated using statistical mechanics.